# i want to array key and array value comma separated string

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array and I want to convert it into string.
I  try to get string from php `implode()` function but could not get the desired result.
The output I want is **`arraykey-arrayvalue`,`arraykey-arrayvalue`,`arraykey-arrayvalue`** and so on as long as array limit end.

```
 Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 )
 $data = implode(",", $pData);
 //it is creating string like
 $data=1,1,1;
 // but i want like below 
 $string=1-1,2-1,3-1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just gather the key pair values inside an array then implode it:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) { $data[] = "$k-$v"; }
echo implode(',', $data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `array_map` function as

```
$arar = Array ( '1' => 1 ,'2' => 1, '3' => 1 );
$result = implode(',',array_map('out',array_keys($arar),$arar));
function out($a,$b){
   return $a.'-'.$b;
}
echo $result;//1-1,2-1,3-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the below code:

```
$temp = '';
$val = '';
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $temp = $key.'-'.$val;
    if($i == 0)
    {
        $val  = $temp; // so that comma does not append before the string starts
        $i = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $val = $val.','.$temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use array_map function and finally implode it.